# Remove unwanted html tags from R using regex

Tags: html, r, regex

I have the following string:

```
aaa<-"\n                                                        \n                                                            267 Oberlin St.\n                                                            \n                                                            New York, New York\n                                                            \n                                                            US, 10018\n                                                        \n                                                    "
```

How can I get rid of the `\n` and empty spaces?

I tried the following:

```
str_replace_all(aaa, "[\n]", "")
[1] "                                                                                                                

    267 Oberlin St.                                                                                                                        New York, New York                                                                                                                        US, 10018  

str_replace_all(aaa, " ", "")
[1] "\n\n267OberlinSt.\n\nNewYork,NewYork\n\nUS,10018\n\n"

str_replace_all(aaa, "[ \n ]", "")
[1] "267OberlinSt.NewYork,NewYorkUS,10018"
```

What I'm looking for is the following:

```
"267 Oberlin St. New York, New York US, 10018"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that you need to remove any 0+ spaces followed with a newline that is followed with 3 or more spaces you may use

```
> trimws(gsub(" *\n {3,}", " ", aaa))
[1] "267 Oberlin St.  New York, New York  US, 10018"
```

Or, a bit more precise, the newline + 3 or more space pattern can be repeated:

```
> trimws(gsub(" *(?:\n {3,})+", " ", aaa))
[1] "267 Oberlin St. New York, New York US, 10018"
```

**Pattern details**

- `*` - 0 or more spaces
- `(?:\n {3,})+` - a non-capturing group matching 1 or more repetitions of:

  - `\n`  - a newline
  - `{3,}` - 3 or more spaces

To match any horizontal whitespaces, you may replace literal space in the pattern with `[[:blank:]]`, or `\h` if you add `perl=TRUE`.